# ssh to remote host on mac

Tags: ssh, vpn, tunnel, ssh-tunnel

it looks like a simple case, but I cannot make it work.
We have an internal CI (Continous Integration) application running on our internal server (lets say its address it ciserver.com and the application is running on the port 8080, so we have ciserver.com:8080). I was told I can get to this server from outside of our office by tunneling through one of our servers (lets say it's address is myserver.com). On my Mac I tried the following command:

```
ssh -N -L -f 6666:ciserver.com:8080 username@myserver.com
```

I was promped for the password, which I entered.

In my browser I tried: http://127.0.0.1:6666 but the webpage did not load.
Any suggestions what I did wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Finally, I got it working. Command: ssh -N -L 2345:ciserver.com:8080 username@myserver.com did the trick, but I don't really know why the first approach did not work as it's basically the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have the command line arguments in the wrong order.  Try ...

```
ssh -N -f -L 6666:ciserver.com:8080 username@myserver.com
```

You can check if the port forwarding has been created by executing `netstat`.

```
netstat -a -p tcp
```

and look at the entries in the LISTEN state.  There should be a line similar to ...

```
Active Internet connections (including servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q  Local Address          Foreign Address        (state)
tcp4       0      0  *.6666                 *.*                    LISTEN
```